# Duplicate table data but modify one column

Tags: sql, db2

In a table i store referntial data for my application by year.
Now when entering a new year i have to duplicate all that data and insert it into the table and increment the year:

example:

```
Year    Value1    Value2    Value3
2013    'aaaa'    'bbbb'    'cccc'
2013    'dddd'    'eeee'    'ffff'
2013    'gggg'    'hhhh'    'iiii'
```

i need this to become:

```
Year    Value1    Value2    Value3
2013    'aaaa'    'bbbb'    'cccc'
2013    'dddd'    'eeee'    'ffff'
2013    'gggg'    'hhhh'    'iiii'    
2014    'aaaa'    'bbbb'    'cccc'
2014    'dddd'    'eeee'    'ffff'
2014    'gggg'    'hhhh'    'iiii'
```

The problem is there are a lot of comumns in the table so it is not really an option to select all the columns manually, but i also can't do a select *, since i need the year to become 2014.

Is there a way to do this in 1 query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a temp table.

```
select * into #temp from mytable where Year=@curent_year

update #temp set Year=Year+1

insert into mytable select * from #temp

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO YOURTABLE SELECT '2014',Value1,Value2,Value3  from YOURTABLE
```

This should work.

Comment: *it is not really an option to select all the columns manually*

Comment: this is the simplest one. next would be dumping value columns in temp table and doing * then